# Difference between Ports in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, service, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I am new to k8 and I am trying to understand the difference between the two services.
Service A:

```
test1  ClusterIP   ##.##.##    <none>        8080/TCP   187d
```

vs

```
test2  LoadBalancer   ##.##.##    ww.blah.com   2888:31218/TCP,8080:30012/TCP   20d
```

1. I understand that one can be accessed through a LoadBalancer (`test2`) and the other is through a ClusterIP(`test1`).
2. For application `test2` I want to expose the port 8080 similar to `test1`

But I am not understanding what  `2888:31218/TCP,8080:30012/TCP` means.
Please can someone explain it to me how can I do something similar for `test2` as it is for `test1` without exposing it via a `ClusterIP`

Comment: Please read this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ports-targetport-nodeport-service.html

Comment: Rather than the `kubectl get service` diagnostic output, can you [edit] the question to include the important parts of the two Service YAML files?  You should be able to connect to the `port:` of both Services from inside the cluster in the same way, even if one is a `type: LoadBalancer`.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your questions in the same order

1. test1 service is defined as ClusterIP, which means that the service is accessible within the kubernetes cluster only.
2. test2 is defined as service type LoadBalancer. It can be accessed externally over internet. Moreover, it has two ports listening on 2888 and 8080. port 2888 is bound to NodePort 31218 and 8080 is bound to 30012 NodePort. The service can also be accessed using the Hostname:NodePort combination using any of the cluster member.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not understanding what 2888:31218/TCP,8080:30012/TCP means.
> Please can someone explain it to me how can I do something similar for
> test2 as it is for test1 without exposing it via a ClusterIP

it's not possible, it might break existing running/exposed service.

> I understand that one can be accessed through a LoadBalancer (test2)
> and the other is through a ClusterIP(test1).

**ClusterIP** services only accessible internally in K8s cluster, which mean microservices and application in same cluster can talk to each other.

While service exposed with **LB** is publicly accessible over the internet mostly.

> For application test2 I want to expose the port 8080 similar to test1

it's already exposed to **8080** & **2888** you will be able to access it over the port.

Ports `30012` & `31218` are NodePort, you can also access the service using these ports. `HTTP://NodeIP:NodePort`

**NodeIP** : where your POD is get schedule

`kubectl get pods -o wide` will give you NodeIP on which POD is running

**nodePort**

> This setting makes the service visible outside the Kubernetes cluster
> by the node’s IP address and the port number declared in this
> property. The service also has to be of type NodePort (if this field
> isn’t specified, Kubernetes will allocate a node port automatically).